# read file in Android test project in my case

Tags: android, android-testing

I have an Android Test project, the project structure looks like this:

```
MyAndroidTestProj
 - src/
      - MyTestCase.java
 - res/
   - raw/
       - file1
```

MyTestCase is like this:

```
public class MyTestCase extends AndroidTestCase {
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        //How to read the file1 under res/raw/ folder?
    }
    ...
}
```

I am wondering how could I read the `file1` under `res/raw/` ? Is there an Android specific way to read the file?

Answer (score 0):

You should first get the id of the resource and than convert it to an InputStream for example to use it's content. So use this code:

```
InputStream ins = getResources()
        .openRawResource(getResources()
        .getIdentifier("raw/FILENAME_WITHOUT_THE_EXTENSION","raw", getPackageName()));
```

and then with one `BufferedReader` you could get the string value of the `InputStream`

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    content.append(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

As commented, the AndroidTestCase does not provide `getInstrumentation`, but it does provide a `getContext()` method, which gives you the context of the tested App. But as you want to get a resource from the test application, you'd need to access the `getTestContext()` method, that is defined inside the AndroidTestCase, but is hidden.

As a workaround you could use reflection to access it like described here:

http://kmansoft.com/2011/04/18/accessing-resources-in-an-androidtestcase/

```
 try {
            Method m = AndroidTestCase.class.getMethod("getTestContext", new Class[] {});
            Context testContext = (Context) m.invoke(this, (Object[]) null);
            testContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file1);
        } catch (Exception x) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting test context: ", x);
            throw x;
        }
```

**Old answer:**

To get raw resources from inside your test project, use

```
getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file1);
```

If you want to get them from the project under test, you have to use the target context instead:

```
getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file1);
```

Comment: My test case extends `AndroidTestCase`, which doesn't have `getInstrumentation()` method.

Comment: I've edited my answer to address the AndroidTestCase.